# Issue in Creating or Updating the Schema in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, schema

I am trying to create/update Schema in BigQuery by passing the below JSON file to bq  as

**update and Create statements as :**

```
bq mk --table [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[TABLE] [PATH_TO_SCHEMA_FILE]
bq update [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[TABLE] [PATH_TO_SCHEMA_FILE]
```

**SCHEMA_FILE:**

```
[
      {
        "mode": "REQUIRED", 
        "name": "cma_id", 
        "type": "STRING"
      }, 
      {
        "mode": "NULLABLE", 
        "name": "address_id", 
        "type": "INTEGER"
      }
]
```

Both the above statements are giving error as `BigQuery error in mk operation: Invalid value for: REQUIRED is not a valid value`

Can someone guide me what Am I Missing in Schema file?

Comment: It works for me using exactly the schema you pasted. Double check your schema file.

Comment: @Pentium10 yeah thanks..I tried it with frontend too...Got it..That was Extra Space as "mode": "REQUIRED " at one column

Comment: Note that you can also use a `CREATE TABLE` statement instead; see the [DDL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data-definition-language).

Answer (score 3):

Just not to leave the question unanswered, the issue was an extra space as "mode": "REQUIRED " at one column (see Shivkumar's comment).